# SQL Server stored procedure sp_updatestats issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a question about stored procedure `sp_updatestats`. My understanding is when upgrading from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008, we need to execute such procedure, but when upgrading from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008, there is no need to execute such stored procedure.

Is my understanding correct? Another question is why from 2000 to 2008 there is need to execute such stored procedure, any reference documents?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Randy Minder's answer, I've never done it.

You should have regular index and/or stats maintenance anyway. An index rebuild includes statistics anyway.

You may want to update stats more often though so you'd run sp_updatestats separately. For example, index rebuild as weekends, stats nightly.

Up to date statistics are *extremely* useful to the query optimiser.

Comment: "You should have regular index and/or stats maintenance anyway" -- how do you do this?

Comment: And executing "sp_updatestats" is of same effect to rebuild index/stats?

Comment: @George2: no, stats only. ALTER INDEX for indexes. See http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+server+index+maintenance+best+practice

Comment: Confused. 1. What is the differences between update stats and update index? 2. sp_updatestats will only update stats?

Comment: @George2: please read the articles in my search. Which is what Randy Minder said...

Comment: I have find out how to do from SSMS GUI, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179349.aspx, but how to do from command line (i.e. tsql command)? To automate the process, I need command line solution.

Comment: @George2: ALTER INDEX as I said which is at the bottom of the link you just posted...

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessary, at least not in my experience. Just get into the habit of regularly rebuilding your indexes and your stats will be updated as well.

Comment: What is the benefit of executing sp_updatestats? "get into the habit of regularly rebuilding your indexes" -- how do you achieve this? Any reference documents?

Comment: @George2 - One easy way of regularly rebuilding your indexes is by creating an SSMS maintenance plan and having it execute once per week (or whatever is appropriate). Regarding the benefit of updating statistics - it's useful in order for the query plan generator to select the correct query execution plan and the use of indexes.

Comment: "SSMS maintenance plan" -- SMSS could be used to rebuild index? Any details or documents?

Comment: And executing "sp_updatestats" is of same effect to rebuild index/stats?

Comment: @George2 - The end result is the same. Statistics will get updated. But you are much better off having a regular rebuild index plan.

Comment: Confused. 1. What is the differences between update stats and update index? 2. sp_updatestats will only update stats?

Comment: Randy, I am wondering normally how do you rebuild index? Any commands or documents to make a reference? :-)

Comment: @George2 - This is a simple Google search or look it up in Books Online.

Comment: I have find out how to do from SSMS GUI, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179349.aspx, but how to do from command line (i.e. tsql command)? To automate the process, I need command line solution.